# How to redirect specifically dependent on Group ID selected

Tags: add-on, forms, solspace-user

I'm new to this forum so hoping you can assist me with something that I've completely hit a dead end with.

I basically need to specify a confirmation page dependent on Group ID selected within a registration form (using the user module).

Below is a link to the thread I have already posted with the module developer but what they have recommended hasnt worked.

http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/14730/#57817

I would've thought something like this would be relatively simple.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks
Scott

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to try the option Nicolas outlined in [his reply](http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/14730/#57907) then you could change the value of the hidden input field using some jQuery easy enough.

Take a look at this working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Tyzsr/1/

It's still rough but should get you going down the right road I hope.